# Setting path directory in a download dialog

Tags: javascript, browser, path, download

Using Javascript, is it possible to have a download window open with the download path preset?  I know I can't force the user to download the file to a certain location, which is fine, but can I preset the filename to the directory to which I'd prefer the file to be saved? At this point, the user can still change directory since it's still within the `download dialog window`, but to save time it would be handy if the text was already preset to the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That would be a security violation.

EDIT: think of *presetting* the download directory to `C:\WINDOWS` and then disguising the download to replace a system file with something more malicious.

Comment: Although the user still has to click on the 'save' button, if they're happy with the filename, I see what you mean. I take it that also means I can't set the dialog folder to automatically open to a specific directory either?

Comment: Nope, you can't do that either. You can specify the filename you want using the `Content-Disposition` header, but you can't do path setting.

Comment: Think I'll have to leave that idea aside then. Thanks a lot for the help.